# How do I align peak labels?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am attempting to graph data with peaks in R. The graphing itself has progressed well, but I've run into issues with labelling the relevant peaks. My current labelling system, detailed below, shifts the peak labels oddly to the side and results in lines crossing each other. Is there a way to align labels with the peaks themselves, or otherwise organize them aesthetically?

The following code reproduces my problem, using [this data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1S345TaPqANriDPLN6H_PyunuM1QHi485/view?usp=sharing).

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpmisc)
library(ggrepel)

x=read.csv("data.csv")

colnames(x)=c("wv", "abs")

ggplot(x, aes(x=wv, y=abs)) + geom_line() + xlab(bquote('Wavenumbers ('~cm^-1*')')) + ylab("Absorbance (A.U.)") + scale_x_reverse(limits=c(2275,1975), expand=c(0,0)) + ylim(-0.01,0.29) + stat_peaks(colour = "black", span = 11,  geom ="text_repel", direction = "y", angle = 90, ignore_threshold = 0.09, size = 3, x.label.fmt = "%.2f", vjust = 1, hjust = 0, segment.color = "red") + ggtitle("FTIR - Carbon Monoxide, Fundamentals")
```

[image: Problematic Labels]

Comment: You could use `stat_label_peaks`, see here https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggspectra/vignettes/userguide1-grammar.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an approach using `ggplot2::stage` and the built-in `segment` and `text` geometries:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpmisc)

id <- "1S345TaPqANriDPLN6H_PyunuM1QHi485"
x <- read.csv(sprintf("https://docs.google.com/uc?id=%s&export=download", id))
colnames(x)=c("wv", "abs")

ggplot(x, aes(x=wv, y=abs)) + geom_line() +
  xlab(bquote('Wavenumbers ('~cm^-1*')')) + ylab("Absorbance (A.U.)") + ggtitle("FTIR - Carbon Monoxide, Fundamentals") + ylim(-0.01,0.29) +
  stat_peaks(mapping = aes(x = stage(wv, after_scale = x + 0.25)),
             geom ="text", colour = "black", span = 11, angle = 90,
             ignore_threshold = 0.09, size = 2.5, x.label.fmt = "%.2f",
             vjust = 0.5, hjust = -1) +
  stat_peaks(mapping = aes(xend = stage(wv, after_scale = x + 0.25),
                           y = stage(abs, after_stat = y + 0.005),
                           yend = after_stat(y + 0.02)),
             geom ="segment", lwd = 0.5, colour = "red", 
             span = 11, ignore_threshold = 0.09) +
  scale_x_reverse(expand=c(0,0), limits = c(2275,1975))
```

[image]

From `help(stat_peaks)` we can see that `x` and `y` stats are calculated for each peak. Typically we can access these stats with `after_stat`, but because you've also transformed the x-axis, you need to actually access that stat after it's been scaled.

In the first layer of `stat_peaks` we use `stage(wv, after_scale = x + 0.25)` to add a bit of nudge to the x coordinate. In the second call of `stat_peaks` we set the geometry to `segment`. Segment requires an `xend` and `yend`. We can use `stage` and `after_stat` to again add a nudge and line length.

Comment: Thank you! When I copy-paste your code, I had to edit out the `+ 0.25` in each `after_scale = x + 0.25)` term to obtain the nice vertical lines in your graph. Do you know why that might be?

Comment: I put those in there to show how you might make non-vertical lines as seen in your question. If you want perfectly vertical lines, just remove it as you have.

Answer (score 3):

`hjust = 0.5` should work better. Using `hjust = 0` aligns your labels a little to the right, with the top edge of the text aligned with the middle of each peak.

Here's a reproducible example that doesn't rely on external data that might not remain available at that link. (See bottom for application to the OP dataset.)

```
library(ggpmisc)
library(ggrepel)
library(ggplot2)
x <- data.frame(wv = 2300:2000)
x$abs = abs(cos(x$wv/50) * sin(x$wv/2))
ggplot(x, aes(wv, abs)) +
  geom_line() +
  stat_peaks(colour = "black", span = 11,  
             geom ="text_repel", direction = "y", 
             angle = 90, ignore_threshold = 0.09, 
             size = 3, x.label.fmt = "%.2f", 
             vjust = 1, hjust = 0.5, segment.color = "red") +
  scale_x_reverse(limits = c(2300,2000))
```

[image]

Here's loading the original data:

```
library(readr)
x <- read_csv("~/Downloads/CO-FTIR Spectrum-1800 mTorr-2021.csv")
colnames(x)=c("wv", "abs")
```

Here with these parameters added:

```
box.padding = 0.0, nudge_y = 0.02,
```

[image]

Comment: Is there any way to avoid the data cutting into the labels?

Comment: This answer just [doesn't seem to work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WEH78.png) on the question author's data.

Comment: Agreed, the even spacing of the peaks here seems to be key to making this work. I would still like any possible clarification on if there's a way to avoid the labels overlapping with the peaks themselves.

Comment: `box.padding = 0.0, nudge_y = 0.02,` are good ggrepel parameters to add for the original data. see updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

I wasn't able to find a way to do this without constructing an auxiliary dataset. However, once constructed the actual plotting then becomes fairly easy:

The code is as follows:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpmisc)
library(ggrepel)
library(pracma)


#####################################
# Constants
#####################################
wvfilter = c(1975, 2275)
data_filename = "data.csv"


#####################################
# Read data
#####################################
dat = read.csv(data_filename)
colnames(dat)=c("wv", "abs")


#####################################
# Identify peaks
#####################################

# Extract peaks
peaks = data.frame(findpeaks(dat$abs, threshold=0, minpeakheight=0.03))
# Give data frame reasonable names
colnames(peaks) = c("height", "x_index", "peak_begin_index", "peak_end_index")
# Convert from index to wavelength
peaks$wv = dat$wv[peaks$x_index]
# Set the y position of the labels
peaks$nudge = 0.3-peaks$height
# Filter by wavelength
peaks = peaks %>% filter(wvfilter[1] <= wv & wv <= wvfilter[2])


#####################################
# Plot data
#####################################

ggplot(x, aes(x=wv, y=abs)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_text_repel(
    data=peaks,
    mapping=aes(x=wv, y=height, label=height),
    force=0,
    nudge_y=peaks$nudge,
    direction="x",
    angle=90,
    segment.color="red"
  ) +
  xlab(bquote('Wavenumbers ('~cm^-1*')')) +
  ylab("Absorbance (A.U.)") +
  scale_x_reverse(limits=rev(wvfilter), expand=c(0,0)) +
  ylim(-0.01,0.29) +
  ggtitle("FTIR - Carbon Monoxide, Fundamentals")
```

And this gives the plot:
[image: A better spectral peak plot]

Some notes:

- In the image I'm using the wrong text for the labels. Fix this with `label=wv` instead of `label=height`.
- The `peaks` dataset needs to be filtered using the same values passed to `scale_x_reverse(limits=`. To simplify this, I've introduced a global variable for setting the x-axis limits.
- Playing with the `force` argument gives different degrees of clustering of the labels. `force=0` seems to work best for your data.
- You need to manually set the `peaks$nudge` value. I don't know of a good way of doing this other than guess-and-check.